# My Discord bot not responding or not receiving my message

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a bot using only asyncio and websockets.
Right now, I'm trying to send "Hi" command that the bot will respond to with "Hello", but it's not working.

Tried to add a check and it returns that no message has been sent.

Code:

```
# Respond
async def send_reply(channel_id, message_id, content):
    reply_payload = {
        "op": 1,
        "d": {
            "type": 1,
            "data": {
                "content": content
            }
        }
    }

    reply_channel = f"wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=9&encoding=json&session_id={session_id}&channel_id={channel_id}&message_id={message_id}"
    async with websockets.connect(reply_channel) as reply_websocket:
        await reply_websocket.send(json.dumps(reply_payload))
        print("❓ Reply sent?")
        response = await reply_websocket.recv()
        response_data = json.loads(response)
        if response_data.get("op") == 11:
            print("✅ Reply sent successfully!")
        else:
            print("❌ Failed to send reply.")

# Message
async def handle_event(event_type, event_data):
    global session_id
    if event_type == "READY":
        print(f" {event_data['user']['username']} is ready to work! (ID: {event_data['user']['id']})")
        session_id = event_data['session_id']
    elif event_type == "MESSAGE_CREATE":
        message_content = event_data["content"]
        print(f" New message content: {message_content}")
        if message_content == "Hi!":
            await send_reply(event_data["channel_id"], event_data["id"], "Hello!")
```

What I tried:

1. Find answers on google *(but for some reason there is only d.py)*.
2. Search the discord documentation

What I expect:

1. Fix, that will make my bot respond to my messages

Comment: How do you hook these functions to the bot?  I don't see any @bot decorators.

Comment: Hi. In case you haven't noticed, there are only asynchronous functions, because I don't use any libraries connected to Discord, such as d.p, disnake, etc. I only use websockets and asyncio for all actions. @TimRoberts

Comment: Instead of using the gateway API to send messages, you can use the HTTP API, by sending a POST request to `/channels/{channel.id}/messages`. Using the gateway API will need you to also manage other things, such as sending an Identify with intents, listening for the ready event, and then closing the websocket. Also, I'm pretty sure your gateway url is invalid anyhow, because session_id, channel_id, and message_id are not in the discord documentation for valid query parameters for the gateway connection url

Comment: Pretty much this is a possible reason why my code doesn't work. @eten